# When do you use 'throughout'?

Tags: grammar

When exacactly do use use the word throughout?

here's an example sentence i struggle with:

In the film, numerous different relationships throughout the family are presented.

Can i leave it like that? i have the feeling that the complete sentence structure is wrong..

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score -1):

May be : In the film, numerous different relationships across the family are presented.